# How to change the permission of a directory inside the .tar.gz file?

Tags: bash, terminal, tar

The command below generates a `i.tar.gz` file from the `.json` files inside the `dir` path. How can I change the `i` directory permission in `i.tar.gz` file to `755`?

```
dir=/Library/WebServer/a/a/f/i
cd "$dir" && exec tar --null -zcvf i.tar.gz -T <(printf '%s\0' *.json)
```

Note: `-pcvzf` is not working also.

Comment: You `cd` to directory i. Are you sure directory i is part of your tar file?

Comment: @LeonVismer,can you implement the command and post your answer?

Comment: Please ask your sysadmin or ask at [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour).